# PHP search array that has a specific key

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
array {
    ["MASTERKEY"]=> "SECONDKEY1, SECONDKEY2, SECONDKEY3, SECONDKEY4" 
    ["OTHERKEY"]=> "SECONDKEY1, SECONDKEY2, SECONDKEY3, SECONDKEY4"
}
```

And I have this function [example only]:

```
    function findbothkeys() {
        $masterkey= 'MASTERKEY';
        $secondkey= 'SECONDKEY2';


        if (array_key_exists($masterkey, $array)) {
            echo 'Yes ' . $masterkey. ' found';
            if (in_array($secondkey, $array[$masterkey])) {
                echo 'Yes' . $secondkey. ' found';
            }
            else {
                echo 'NO' . $secondkey. ' not found';
            }
        }
        else {
            echo 'NO' . $masterkey. ' not found';
        }
}
```

The thing I want to achieve is that after the string of `$masterkey` is found as a KEY of that array -> the next search (`in_array`) should only be performed in the value of that. Not in the other Key-Values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `in_array` function expects the second argument to be an array, but in your case it is a string.

One way to solve this, is to turn the string into an array with `explode`:

```
in_array($secondkey, explode(", ", $array[$masterkey]))
```